# I need help running specific playwright commands in an azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, playwright

Fairly new to configuring things in ADO but the jist is I have a test pipeline that fires off 200+ tests that can take a good 40ish minutes to complete.

I know playwright lets you run commands that only run specific tests like

`npx playwright test [folderName]`

I essentially want to do this in the pipeline but whenever a change in a specific area of the app is detected that way I only execute the relevant tests opposed to all 200+.

What would the best way to do this and is there documentation I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I essentially want to do this in the pipeline but whenever a change in a specific area of the app is detected that way I only execute the relevant tests opposed to all 200+.

Based on your description, you need to run the relevant tests based on the changed folder in Repo.

To meet your requirement, you can refer to the following steps to achieve it in Azure Pipeline.

Step1: You need to use git command(git diff) to get the changed folder names in the repo.

Then you can set the folder path as Pipeline variable with the [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).

File path:

[image]

Here is the PowerShell script sample:

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
$temp=$files -split ' '
$count=$temp.Length
echo "Total changed $count files"
For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
{
  $name=$temp[$i]
  echo "this is $name file"
  if ($name -like '*/api-mocking/*')  #if api-mocking is a subfolder under a folder use "- like '*/api-mocking/*'"
  {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=APIfolder]tests/api-mocking"
  }
  if ($name -like '*/boxed-steps/*')
  {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=boxedfolder]tests/boxed-steps"
  }
}
```

**Note:** we need to set the `fetchDepth: 0` when checkout the repo.

Step2: You can directly use the Pipeline variable(Created by powershell script) in the  `npx playwright test` command. We can use the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages) to make sure that the variable has actual value.

For example:

```
- script: 'npx playwright test $(APIfolder) $(boxedfolder)'
  condition: OR(ne(variables['APIfolder'], ' '), ne(variables['boxedfolder'], ' '))
```

Full YAML sample:

```
variables:
  APIfolder: ' '
  boxedfolder: ' '

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0

- powershell: |
           $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
           $temp=$files -split ' '
           $count=$temp.Length
           echo "Total changed $count files"
           For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
           {
             $name=$temp[$i]
             echo "this is $name file"
             if ($name -like '*/api-mocking/*')  #if api-mocking is a subfolder under a folder use "- like '*/api-mocking/*'"
             {
               Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=APIfolder]tests/api-mocking"
             }
             if ($name -like '*/boxed-steps/*')
             {
               Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=boxedfolder]tests/boxed-steps"
             }
           }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    verbose: false

- script: 'npx playwright test $(APIfolder) $(boxedfolder)'
  condition: Or(ne(variables['APIfolder'], ' '), ne(variables['boxedfolder'], ' '))
```

**Result:**

When the changes not in test folder, it will skip the playwright test.

[image]

When the changes are in the target folder, it will run the playwright test based on folder path.

[image]